# C/C++ implementation of a Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

As novice,  I m trying to generate a DAG with C (or C++).

```
struct Node
{
    Link *incomingEdge, *outgoingEdge;
};

struct Link
{

    Node *origin, *destination;

};
```

simply in my code there are only one incoming and outgoing edges for each node. However, a node could have several incident edges. Moreover, number of incident edges might change for each node.

how can I generate different number of pointers for each node ?

assume that I have;

nodeA with 5 incoming edges and 4 outgoing edges.
nodeB with 3 incoming edges and 6 outgoing edges.

so number of pointers are changing for each node.

Comment: _'how can I generate different number of pointers for each node ?'_ What do you mean with _generate_? Are you asking, how to hold more than a single pointer for incident edges? Then you can use something like `std::vector<Link*> incidentEdges;`.

Comment: You might want to consider using an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). Also: if you're planning on using one structure rather than another one perhaps programmers.se could be a better choice.

Comment: well, I would like to often delete nodes and edges and add news ones..That is why I dont want to consider adjacency lists.

Comment: a vector container would be nice but if I want to often search through vector, is it an efficient way ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a vector of pointers

```
std::vector<Link *> incomingEdge;
```

Comment: I think I got the trick. But if I want to often search through the incomingEdge vector that whether it has a specific Edge or not, do I need to use find() function? or is there any other efficient way ?

Comment: if you need often to lookup for particular edge, use std::map<key, Link*> or std::set<Link*>, depending on your data structures. Both of this containers have find member-functions

Comment: but how can I declare this vector (points another struct Link) in Node struct. my compiler didnt work.

Comment: Find certainly works.   If the number of edges is large per node, then a map may be preferred.   If that isn't fast enough maybe some sort of  hashing on the pointers into some sort of bayesian thing might work.   I suggest starting with the simplest idea, getting it working, then looking at the performance.   It may be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need. The graph is completely desccribed by the edges, so the easy answer is, omit `*incomingEdge, *outgoingEdge` from the node definition.
But a linked list or an appropriate container from `std::` of adjecent nodes will be probably be better for the algorithms you are going to implement.

Comment: well, the graph is directed and the direction of the links are important..a node in linked list can show only *next, and *previous nodes. but if there are 5 *next nodes ?

Comment: I meant somthing like 

The singly linked lists of incoming and othoing adjecencies may look like.
`struct Link
{
    Link *theEge, *nextIOEdge;
};`

Comment: I really didnt get it. Could you please explain it little bit.